# Consulta de filas a columnas MySQL para enviar valores a php

Tags: php, mysql, select, sql

```
Tengo estas 3 tablas

||               usuario              ||
||------------------------------------||
|| nombre || apellido ||   documentoU ||
|| Andres || Perez    ||    123456    ||



||            usuario_info_usuario               ||
||-----------------------------------------------||
|| id || documentoU || idInfo ||    infoValor    ||
|| 1  || 123456     ||   1    ||     123456789   ||
|| 2  || 123456     ||   1    ||     987654321   ||
|| 3  || 123456     ||   2    || cor@correo.com  || 


||      info_usuario    ||
||----------------------||
|| idInfo  ||   nombre  ||
||    1    || telefono  || 
||    2    || correo    || 

El resultado de usuario_info_usuario es

|| documentoU || nombre || apellido ||    infoValor  ||
||---------------------------------------------------|| 
|| 123456     || Andres || Perez    ||   123456789   ||
|| 123456     || Andres || Perez    ||   987654321   ||
|| 123456     || Andres || Perez    ||cor@correo.com ||

Pero necesito que quede así

|| documentoU || nombre || apellido ||   a     ||     b   ||       c      || 
||------------------------------------------------------------------------|| 
|| 123456     || Andres || Perez    ||123456789||987654321||cor@correo.com||
```

Para poder sacar las columnas en php, o si hay otra forma de tomar los valores de las filas,

si hago group by se pierden los valores, tengo este sql buscando dividir por columnas los valores pero quedan con NULL los campos vacios.

```
SELECT u.num_documento_usuario,
    u.nombre,
    u.apellido,
    u.tipo_documento,
    coalesce((case when i.id_info_usuario = '2' then i.info_usuario_valor end), NULL) as A,
    coalesce((case when i.id_info_usuario = '11' then i.info_usuario_valor end), NULL) as B
FROM usuario AS u
INNER JOIN usuario_info_usuario AS i 
    ON i.num_documento_usuario = u.num_documento_usuario 
INNER JOIN info_usuario AS inf ON inf.id_info_usuario=i.id_info_usuario 
WHERE inf.nombre_info IN ('tel_celular' ,'correo') 
GROUP BY u.num_documento_usuario, u.nombre, u.apellido, u.tipo_documento
```

Gracias,

Comment: el tema es que cuantos teléfonos y/o correos puede tener cada usuarios ya que Andres puede tener de A a F en teléfonos y otro usuario puede tener solamente A en teléfonos y el resto en null.

Comment: Te sugiero ser más específico en los datos asociados al usuario. Por ejemplo si tienes más de un teléfono, colocar algo como esto: teléfono casa, teléfono trabajo... otra clasificación podría ser: telefono1, telefono2, telefono3... de esa manera podrías transformar correctamente la fila en columna y no quedarían filas repetidas si el usuario tiene más de un teléfono o correo.

Comment: La verdad es que hay bastante controversia entre tu descripción y tu consulta. Para empezar, el campo `u.tipo_documento` no aparece en tus datos, pero lo usas y agrupas por él. Además, en la consulta sólo incluyes `A` y `B` pero en tu resultado deseado quieres `A`, `B` y `C`. ¿En tus datos siempre habrá `A`, `B` y `C`, o puede haber también `D`, `E`, `F`...? Con la confusión en la pregunta y la información que aportas creo que nadie va a poder ayudarte